# how to get selected rows in QTableView

Tags: qt, row, qtableview

After watching many threads about getting selected rows numbers, I am really confused.

How do you get ROW numbers in `QTableView` using `QStandardItemModel` I used below selection model and behavior as

```
setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
```

and if you have your own way of selecting can you explain how it works.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 79):

The method `selectionModel()` return a `QItemSelectionModel`.

You can use `QItemSelectionModel` class to check/change/other selection(s)

Example:

```
QItemSelectionModel *select = table->selectionModel();

select->hasSelection() //check if has selection
select->selectedRows() // return selected row(s)
select->selectedColumns() // return selected column(s)
...
```

Comment: For reference: the method was [inherited from `QAbstractItemView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel).

Answer (score 22):

Check [`selectedRows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows) method of the [`QItemSelectionModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html) Class .

```
QModelIndexList selection = yourTableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();

// Multiple rows can be selected
for(int i=0; i< selection.count(); i++)
{
    QModelIndex index = selection.at(i);
    qDebug() << index.row();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the model name instad of the table name?

Answer (score 9):

try:

```
QModelIndexList indexList = yourTableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
int row;
foreach (QModelIndex index, indexList) {
    row = index.row();
    ....
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you parse a column, will you drop the same row twice (or more likely some other row).

Answer (score 1):

Since you use

```
yourTableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
yourTableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
```

so only one row can be selected each time, then you can try this:

```
auto rowList = yourTableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
if(rowList.count() > 0)
    int rowNumber = rowList.constFirst().row();
else
    // no row is selected
```