# QTableView how to find out if Row is selected?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a QTableview that has a QTableModel set to it.

This view can be modified eg. rows/columns shifted and removed etc.

I have a function to export a table model to excel/csv which takes a QTableModel, however the model doesnt reflect the view if its been modified, so i have a function that creates a new table model based on the QTableViews current layout.

However i now want to be able to select a few rows and export only the selected, so in essence i need to just create a model based on selected rows in the view not all of them.

below shows my current loop,

```
// Loop over the view's data and add it to the map for the model
for(int i = 0; i < rowIndexs.size(); ++i)
{
    // Loop over visible headers only as we are matching the view not the model
    for(int j = 0; j < headersIndexs.size(); ++j)
    {
        // Column is the logical index of the visual index of the current column, this         values is used as which column to look at in the model to get the cell data
        int column = this->horizontalHeader()->logicalIndex(headersIndexs.at(j));
        int row = this->verticalHeader()->logicalIndex(rowIndexs.at(i));

        /// add to some data container thats not important for this question....

    }
```

so now to make only rows that are selected get added into my container i want to just check is this row selected eg.

```
    if(this->VerticalHeader()->at(row).isSelected)
    { 
         // Add it to the container
    }
    else
    {
         // Ignore it and just go to the next one
    }
```

Does such an `isSelected` function exist on QTableView Rows? if so what is it ??

Cheers

Comment: this seems similar to your question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5927499/942596

Comment: not MY question my cheers ill take a look

Comment: This also doesnt actually answer my question, i should maybe be more clear in my description. I have got my columns and rows already based on if they are hidden or not with `this->verticalHeader()->isSectionHidden(i)` so i cant really use the `SelectedIndexs()` function thats why i ask if there is a `isSelected` function for a specific row...

Comment: Yes, there is such function: `QItemSelectionModel::isSelected (const QModelIndex &index)`

Comment: Cheers that seems exactly what i need but i dont have the QModelIndes position of my row and column i just have the row and column integer values??

Comment: @AngryDuck, you can get the `QModelIndex` from your table's model: `QAbstractTableModel::index(int row, int column, ...)`

Comment: so with use of variable from my code shown above the answer would be `if(this->selectionModel()->isSelected(this->indexAt(QPoint(row, column))))`

Comment: Use http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel to get list of selected items.

Comment: I dont need the list of selected items please read the question i just need to check if a single row is selected or not i see on that link a function `isRowSelected` but it wants a row and a QModelIndex? what is the QModelIndex i pass thats the bit i dont get

Comment: As in QModelindex  &parent ..... whats parent refering to??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
QItemSelectionModel *select = tableview->selectionModel();
```

QItemSelctionModel has following calls to retrieve the list of QModelIndex.

```
QModelIndexList selectedColumns ( int row = 0 ) const
QModelIndexList selectedIndexes () const
QModelIndexList selectedRows ( int column = 0 ) const
```

From QModelIndex to col and row

```
int row = modelindex.row()
int col = modelindex.col()
```

From (row, col) to QModelIndex

```
QModelIndex idx = QTableModel->index(row, col)
```

Comment: `QItemSelectionModel` also has a method `isRowSelected()`, but in addition to a row number it also wants `const QModelIndex &parent`, and I'm a bit mystified as to where to obtain that...