# How to retrieve the selected row(s) of a QTableView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, selection, qtableview

I'm using the `QTableView` class with this model:

```
class PaletteTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self,colors = [[]],headers =[],parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__colors=colors
        self._headers=headers

    def rowCount(self,parent): 
        return len(self.__colors)
    
    def columnCount(self,parent):
        return 6        
    
    def headerData(self,section,orientation,role):
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._headers[section]  
            else:
                return QtCore.QString("Credit %1").arg(section+1) 
            
    def data(self,index,role):
        if role==QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            row=index.row
            return "Crédit"
        if role==QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row=index.row()
            column=index.column()
            return self.__colors[row][column]
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row=index.row()
            column=index.column()
            value=self.__colors[row][column]
            return value  

    def setData(self,index,value,role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role==QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row =index.row()
            column=index.column()
            ch=(value)
            
            self.__colors[row][column]=ch
            self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)
            return True
                
    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
```

I want to retrieve the selected row of this table-view. (And I want to have Python code, if possible).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get selected rows in QTableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927499/how-to-get-selected-rows-in-qtableview)

Answer (score 34):

It depends what you mean by "the selected row". By default, a `QTableView` has its [selection mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionMode-prop) set to `ExtendedSelection`, and its [selection behavior](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop) set to `SelectItems`. This means that several individual table cells in different rows and columns can be selected at the same time. So which one should count as "the" selected row?

The [selection model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) of the table-view has a [selectedRows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedRows) method which will return a list of indexes for the rows where *all the colums* are selected (i.e. as it is when you click on the header section for a row):

```
    indexes = table.selectionModel().selectedRows()
    for index in sorted(indexes):
        print('Row %d is selected' % index.row())
```

However, if you want to get all the rows where *at least one* cell is selected, you can use the [selectedIndexes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#selectedIndexes) method:

```
    rows = sorted(set(index.row() for index in
                      self.table.selectedIndexes()))
    for row in rows:
        print('Row %d is selected' % row)
```

Comment: You can also ensure only one row is selected by table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows) and table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)

Answer (score 8):

One of the way's you can use to retrieve the selected rows is:

```
tableView = QtGui.QTableView()
tableModel = PaletteTableModel()   
tableView.setModel(tableModel)

x = tableView.selectedIndexes ()
```

"tableView.selectedIndexes ()" returns a list-of-QModelIndex's

Answer (score 7):

In my case I use this action into a function that is called in doubleClicked event something like this:
I add this line code into the init function

```
self.tableSusAmigos.doubleClicked.connect(self.doubleClicked_table)
```

After that I declared doubleClicked_table like this:

```
def doubleClicked_table(self):
    index = self.tableSusAmigos.selectedIndexes()[0]
    id_us = int(self.tableSusAmigos.model().data(index).toString())
    print ("index : " + str(id_us))
```

In this case I show an id (integer) that it's in the first column (that's the reason the number 0 in selectedIndexes()[0])