# How do I get values form selected rows of a QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt, selection, qtableview

I am working with a QTableView and trying to retrieve values from the selected row(s). At other times I will be working with mulitiple rows using:

```
self.tableView5.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
```

The code below works, but only when the first row is selected. However, it shows:

```
identity[row].append(str(self.table_model5.data(index)))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

when another row is clicked.

```
names = []
emails = []
identity = []
data = sorted(set(index.row() for index in self.tableView5.selectionModel().selectedRows()))
for row in data:
    identity.append([])
    for column in range(0,2):
        index = self.table_model5.index(row, column)
        identity[row].append(str(self.table_model5.data(index)))
for item in identity:
    names.append(item[0])
    emails.append(item[1])
for name, recipient in zip(names, emails):
    print(name, recipient)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577327/how-to-retrieve-the-selected-row-of-a-qtableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is caused by the convoluted method you are using to populate the lists of values. I would suggest the following simplification:

```
names = []
emails = []
identity = []
for index in sorted(self.tableView5.selectionModel().selectedRows()):
    row = index.row()
    name = self.table_model5.data(self.table_model5.index(row, 0))
    email = self.table_model5.data(self.table_model5.index(row, 1))
    identity.append((name, email))            
    names.append(name)
    emails.append(email)
```

Note that there is no need to use `set`, because `selectedRows` only returns one index per selected row.

Answer (score 0):

It's `identity[row]` that throws this exceptions. Imagine you selected from the table rows 2 and 3. Then in the first iteration of your `for row in data:` loop the value of `row` will be 2 while your `identity` list will be one element long at that time.

Debug and fix your logic.